ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.preprocessing.text'
I try to implement an import keras.preprocessing.text on Jupyter, and I facing this problem
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.preprocessing.text'

I tried this command "pip list" on Anaconda Prompt to see if I have Keras library or not, and I found the library. I don't know how to fix this problem.

always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback. It will be also more readable in question, and more people can see it - so more people may help.

maybe you shouldn't check it on Anaconda Prompt because you may not run code with anaconda. maybe in code run print( sys.executable ) to see /full/path/to/python and install with /full/path/to/python -m pip install ...

Are you sure keras.preprocessing.text is the correct module name?  Did you write that import yourself, or did you follow some example?

I had a similar issue. It turns out that the module should be tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.text.
Here is the reference: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing
